# How can I replicate a search strategy described in a publication?

Tags: publications, literature-search, review-articles, pubmed

I found a Cochrane Review from 2012. I would like to perform a new search with the same search strategy to see if there are an updates in this topic.
The search strategy is given at the bottom of this post.

Now my questions: Where can I input those keywords? Did they perform every line a whole new search, or are those keywords linked together via one search.

I have access to OVID and read/watched some tutorials but they didn't show me something similar.

---

The search strategy:

> Appendix 1. MEDLINE via OVID search strategy
>
> 1. Molar, Third/
> 2. (“third molar*” or “wisdom tooth” or “wisdom teeth” or “3rd molar*” or third-molar).mp.
> 3. T ooth, impacted/
> 4. ((tooth adj5 impact$) or (teeth adj5 impact$)).mp.
> 5. T ooth, unerupted/
> 6. unerupt$.mp.
> 7. 1 or 2
> 8. 3 or 4 or 5 or 6
> 9. 7 and 8
> 10. T ooth extraction/
> 11. (extract$ or remov$).mp.
> 12. asymptom$.mp.
> 13. (symptomless or symptom-free or “symptom free”).mp.
> 14. (trouble-free or “trouble free”).mp.
> 15. or/10-14
> 16. 9 and 15
>
> The above subject search was linked to the Cochrane Highly Sensitive Search Strategy (CHSSS) for identifying randomised
>   trials in MEDLINE: sensitivity maximising version (2008 revision) as
>   referenced in Chapter 6.4.11.1 and detailed in box 6.4.c of the
>   Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviews of Interventions version
>   5.1.0 (updated March 2011).
>
> 1. randomized controlled trial.pt.
> 2. controlled clinical trial.pt.
> 3. randomized.ab.
> 4. placebo.ab.
> 5. drug therapy.fs.
> 6. randomly.ab.
> 7. trial.ab.
> 8. groups.ab.
> 9. or/1-8
> 10. exp animals/ not humans.sh.
> 11. 9 not 10

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at the [Cochrane Handbook](http://handbook.cochrane.org/). What you have are two searches. The first is a search for papers about 3rd molars. The 2nd is the [CHSSS](http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_6/box_6_4_a_cochrane_hsss_2008_sensmax_pubmed.htm) and is used to find the RCT studies from the search of the 3rd molars. You need to enter the search items exactly as the history shows since some steps refer to previous steps (e.g., step 9 of the first search refers to steps 7 and 8).